# Is there a metric that makes $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ a complete metric space?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, natural-numbers, hausdorff-distance

Denote the set of extended natural numbers $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty \}$ by $X$. Is there any metric $D$ that makes $X$ a complete metric space? In other words a distance function $D: \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $D(n,m)\geq 0$
2. $D(n,m)= 0$ if, only if, $m=n$
3. $D(m,n)=D(n,m)$
4. $D(m,n)\leq D(m,p)+D(p,n)$

**My attempt.** I tried using the metric $d(m,m)= \frac{|n-m|}{1+|m-n|}$ of $\mathbb{N}$ to produce a metric on $X=\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$. Necessarily I made some additional definitions like

- $|n\pm\infty|=\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
- $|\infty\pm n|=\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
- $1+\infty=\infty$
- $|\infty-\infty|=0$
- $ \frac{\infty}{\infty}=1$

Define
$$D(m,n)=\sum_{k=\min(m,n)}^{\max(m,n)}\frac{1}{2^k}d(\min(m,n),k).$$

Proof of 1.( $D(m,n) \geq 0$ for all $m,n \in X$): Since $d(\min(m,n),k) \geq 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $D(m,n) \geq 0$.

Proof of 2. ($D(m,n) = 0$ if and only if $m = n$): If $m = n$, then we have $\min(m,n) = \max(m,n) = m$, and $d(m,k) = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. So $D(m,n) = 0$. If $D(m,n) = 0$, then each term in the sum is zero, and since each term is non-negative, this implies that $d(\min(m,n),k) = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\min(m,n) \leq k \leq \max(m,n)$. In particular, this implies that $\min(m,n) = \max(m,n)$, i.e., $m = n$.

Proof of 3. ($D(m,n) = D(n,m)$ for all $m,n \in X$): Just note that $\min(m,n) = \min(n,m)$ and $\max(m,n) = \max(n,m)$, so $D(m,n) = D(n,m)$.

Now the triangular inequality. But I was not able to prove the triangular inequality. In fact, I think that $D$ may not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: The discrete metric makes any space a complete metric space: $D(m,n) = 0$ if $m=n$, and $D(m,n)=1$ if $m\neq n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this $D$ of yours satisfies the triangle inequality or not. It is quite complicated. Still, answering your original question:

> Is there a metric that makes $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ a complete metric space?

Sure. The simplest example is the discrete metric $d(x,y)=1$ (whenever $x\neq y$). This will work for any set.

For more sophisticated example consider $Y=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ (which is compact and thus complete) and any bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}\to Y$. Such bijection exists since both are countable. Then define metric on $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ by transfering from the (Euclidean) metric on $Y$:

$$d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$$

Comment: Note to the OP that the second example here yields a **compact** metric space, which is a much better thing! This might be controversial, but I'd say that usually when one instinctively wants completeness, what one *actually* wants is compactness or at least local compactness.

Comment: @freakish Interesting answer. But I think that bijection must be monotonous. Something like $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$ if $n>0$ and $f(0)=\infty$.

Comment: @EliasCosta no, it doesn't have to be. It's irrelevant. Literally **any** bijection does the job. Because with such definition $f$ becomes a homeomorphism, even isometry, and so both spaces share all topological and metric properties. Including being complete.

Answer (score 2):

Define $d(m,n) = |m-n|$ for $m,n$ natural and $d(\infty,n) = 1+|n|$ for $n$ natural.

To see that this is a metric, define the map $i: \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty \} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $i(n) = (n,0)$ and $i(\infty) = (0,1)$, then
$d(a,b) = \|i(a)-i(b)\|_1$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty \}$.

Another example would be $d(m,n) = |\arctan m -\arctan n|$ for $m,n$ natural and $d(\infty,n) = {\pi \over 2} - \arctan n$ for $n$ natural.

Comment: Do you intend that to mean the usual Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^2$? Because that looks wrong to me - where's the square root? Your $d( )$ looks more like the one induced by my idea, which leaves $\mathbb N$ alone, and maps $\infty$ to $0$ in $\mathbb R$, assuming $0$ is not part of $\mathbb N$. This drops the "$1+$" from the definition of $d( )$, so maybe you were mapping $\infty$ to $-1$? Or you were thinking $\mathbb Z$ instead of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Well, I meant the taxicab norm, but any norm will do as long as the first definition is repaired to match. The point was that elaborate constructions are not needed for such things, embedding will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Embed your set into $\Bbb R$ by identifying the points with the set $ \{1, \frac12, \frac13, \dots, 0\}$ and then use the usual metric on $\Bbb R$.

In detail: consider the mapping $f:\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\} \to \Bbb R$ defined by $$\begin{align}
f(\infty) & = 0 \\\\
f(n) & = \frac1n \qquad \text{for integer $n$}
\end{align}
$$

and let $$D(a, b) = |f(a) - f(b)|.$$

(This is very similar in concept to [copper.hat's suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4655739/25554) but a little simpler.)